# Request to get calendar events responses 404, given the permission assigned and accessToken got using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I want to build a web application which has the function to get other peoples' calendar events. I has register the app on `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/` and requested `Calendars.Read` permission. And I'm sure the Admin has consented to assign these permissions (which I let him to do through the adminconsent page).

[image]

Below is my ASP.Net Controller code aimed to test the Events API. The targeted API is:

```cs
MicrosoftGraphCalendarApi = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}/events";
```

```cs
public async Task<string> GetUserCalendar()
{
    ConfidentialClientApplication cc =
        new ConfidentialClientApplication(Globals.ClientId, Globals.RedirectUri,
            new ClientCredential(Globals.ClientSecret),
            null,
            new TokenCache());

    AuthenticationResult result =
        await cc.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string requestUrl = String.Format(Globals.MicrosoftGraphCalendarApi, "lizhuowei@intl.zju.edu.cn");

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return json;
}
```

When invoked, it seems I managed to get the `accessToken`. However, the request to get `events` responds a `404` error. Below is the complete response:

```cs
{
    StatusCode : 404,
    ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found',
    Version : 1.1,
    Content : System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers:
    { 
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      request-id: 34f1f9b3-34c9-444f-9037-5446884e3fb9
      client-request-id: 34f1f9b3-34c9-444f-9037-5446884e3fb9
      x-ms-ags-diagnostic: 
        {
            "ServerInfo":
            {
                "DataCenter": "East Asia",
                "Slice": "SliceA",
                "ScaleUnit": "000",
                "Host": "AGSFE_IN_2",
                "ADSiteName": "HKG"
            }
        }      
      Duration: 1250.6509
      Cache-Control: private
      Date: Fri, 03 Nov 2017 02:53:03 GMT
      Content-Type: application/json
    }
}
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

I have no idea where the issue may lie. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Does this user have a mailbox and have they access their calendar?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Solved. See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved. The user has to 'share' or 'publish' the targeted calendar first. Otherwise other accounts cannot get access to it even with the admin's consent.

Comment: Hi @D_S_toowhite could you elaborate the steps needed to share/publish the user's calendar. Thanks for your post

Comment: @SrikanthKyatham Open Calendar in O365, Go to Settings > Calendar > Shared Calendars > Publish a calendar. Make sure the calendar you are trying to access is published.