# Microsoft Graph API /me/calendars endpoint inexplicably returns 404

Tags: node.js, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API (and Node.js library) to query a user's calendars. This has worked for many users, but for one user in particular I am unable to query calendars using `/me/calendars` and get the following error: `{statusCode: 404, code: "ResourceNotFound", message: "Resource could not be discovered."}`.

I know that the user hasn't revoked permission for my app, because querying `/me` continues to work.

After some searching online, I'm wondering if this has something to do with a calendar that's been shared with this user, but I'm having trouble finding any more information.

The full list of permissions I request is:

```
Calendars.Read
Calendars.Read.Shared
Contacts.Read
Contacts.Read.Shared
email
Mail.Read
Mail.Read.Shared
offline_access
openid
People.Read
profile
User.Read
User.ReadBasic.All
```

Comment: If you try with /users/email/calendars instead what do you get? And targeting the same user but logged as another one? Does this user have an exchange license?

Comment: Are you sure they have a valid mailbox in the tenant? You can confirm this by having them try to login to [Outlook for the web](https://outlook.office.com/owa/).

Comment: @baywet - I attempted /users/email address/calendars, but I still get a 404 ResourceNotFound error. As for if the user has an Exchange license, I don't know. Do you know how I can figure that out?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I'm not positive, but I've been assuming so since they were able to authenticate and grant my application access.

Comment: Authentication is happening at the Azure AD level, Exchange isn't involved in that process. A user can have a valid Azure AD and still not have a mailbox in Exchange

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087825/488666