# Use Graph API to list events but always get 404 ErrorItemNotFound

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I want to get all events in one of my calendar, so that I use “[List calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0)” first, find the corresponding calendar id, and send [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) with this id.

However, the server always responses 404: ErrorItemNotFound after I send “List events”.

Is it any problem on this calendar or just a temporary server problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. It is really hard to diagnose what is going on without seeing the actual responses to your queries.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks for your suggestions. I have refined my question.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087825/488666